# Uso de dois WITH

Tags: with

Na sentença a seguir, onde tenho que corrigir?

```
WITH ITEM AS
(SELECT 1 COD, 'Tratam./Hormônio' NOME, 1 VENDA 
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Vacina', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Nutricional', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Pastagem', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Ração', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'Procedimento', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'Mat.Laboratório', 1)

WITH VENDA AS
(SELECT 1 COD, 'À vista' DESCRIÇÃO
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'A prazo')

SELECT ITEM.COD, ITEM.NOME, VENDA.DESCRIÇÃO
FROM ITEM
JOIN VENDA ON ITEM.VENDA=VENDA.COD
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Mensagem 319, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

Na verdade preciso usar dois WITH numa situação um pouco diferente. Criei este exemplo pra facilitar.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Você não precisa colocar duas vezes o `with`, basta separar por vírgula: `with item as (...), venda as (...) select ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
 WITH ITEM AS
    (SELECT 1 COD, 'Tratam./Hormônio' NOME, 1 VENDA  from dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Vacina', 1 from dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Nutricional', 2 from dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Pastagem', 2 from dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Ração', 1 from dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'Procedimento', 2 from dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'Mat.Laboratório', 1 from dual),
    VENDA AS
    (SELECT 1 COD, 'À vista' DESCRIÇÃO from dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'A prazo' from dual)

    SELECT ITEM.COD, ITEM.NOME, VENDA.DESCRIÇÃO
    FROM ITEM
    JOIN VENDA ON ITEM.VENDA=VENDA.COD;
```

Sua Sintaxe está errada, o with não deve repetir, só usa uma virgula como no exemplo acima.